# Concatenation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

when I run this code:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('$', '        ', a * 0.05 + b * 12) AS value
```

Variables `a` and `b` are defined as `money` datatype

Comment: The above *won't* generate that error, not if both `a` and `b` are a `money` data type. `money`, `int` and `decimal` can all be implicitly converted to each other without issue, and `CONCAT` automatically implicitly casts each parameter to a `(n)varchar` when concatenating. If you are getting that error, either that isn't your SQL, or your statement that both `a` and `b` are `money` is false. If both are `money` the statement runs fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2077533c72bef84aad71661252cba40e)

Comment: Honestly, though, it seems like you're trying to implement formatting rules in the SQL layer; these are best performed in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the arithmetic expression to text before including it as a parameter in the `CONCAT()` function:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('$', ' ', CAST(a * 0.05 + b * 12 AS varchar(20))) AS value;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I am still getting same error.

Comment: I am not getting any error, [see the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3c4403874d1c1843c4e87aeeb036718).

Comment: `CONCAT` automatically implicitly converts values in it to a `varchar`; this won't actually change anything. If the OP was getting the error, is wasn't due to the lack of explicit casting. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbf6b678670eb0b41eda79657cf9ae45)